# Sculpting tool not working when using tablet

Tags: sculpting

I just started to learn blender.
I got a pan tablet to try the sculpting.
However, when I used the pen of the tablet, sculpting brushes stopped working except the clay brush.
It was working with mouse, but after using the pen, it stopped working with mouse too.
I searched everywhere about it but couldn't find any answer...
How should I solve this problem?

Comment: Start by checking if the pen tablet works with other aps on your system, especially windows.  Then edit  settings and take a look at the Input section.  Do the mouse settings look reasonable? What are the tablet settings?  (On windows go with Tablet API Automatic).  Finally in sculpt mode, to the right of "Radius" and to the right of "Strength" in the menu bar on top of the 3D viewport, there are two buttons that look like a pencil and a bunch of circles.  Check to see that at most one of those is set.

Comment: Not sure how likely it is, but I suspect that pressure and velocity sensitivity settings are causing issues somewhere by resulting in strengths that are too low. Try turning these dynamic options off if they are on.